# Scroll programmatically has no effect on UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have the following `UIWebView` implementation and I want to set the scroll after the webview is loaded. However, scroll programmatically has no effect on `UIWebView`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.xxxx.com/private-dining";

    //Create a URL object.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

    //URL Requst Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [privateDiningWebView loadRequest:requestObj];

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        privateDiningWebView.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 300);
    });
}
```

Comment: you should not call this method in `vieDidLaoad`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set delegate for UIWebview and try this code :

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
     privateDiningWebView.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 300);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to call this in `webView` is Finish loading web content .

don't forget to add `UIWebViewDelegate` in you ViewController

```
  – webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
    {
     // UI Operation should be Done in Main Queue so you need to get 
     // main Queue to Access your webView
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         privateDiningWebView.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 300);

      });

    }
```